# golang dep add says "<path> is already imported or required, so -add is only valid with a constraint", what does it means?

Tags: go, dependencies, godeps

I'm trying to add a dependency to the vendor directory and I'm getting this really strange error:

```
dep ensure -add github.com/google/uuid
```

And the error says:

> `github.com/google/uuid` is already imported or required, so -add is only valid with a constraint

At some point, while writing my code, I did:

```
git get github.com/google/uuid
```

and now I'd like to add `uuid` to my `vendor/...` directory.

But as far as I know it should have no side effect, correct?